# How to solve the following GR PDE?

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

Someone could help me for solving the following GR PDE? (this code do not work yet)

```
E0 = 1; G = 1; c = 1; 
R = 5; T = 1/3; 

Cte = Sqrt[(E/Pi/R^3)*(E0/(4/T^2 + 1/R^2))]
Phi = Cte*Exp[(-r/2)*R]*Exp[(-t^2/4)*T^2]; 
pressure = (1/2)*(Exp[2*F[r, t]]*D[Phi, t]^2 + D[Phi, r]^2)

eqrr = ((-c^2)*E^(2*F[r, t]) + 
E^(2*H[r, t])*((-E^(2*F[r, t]))*
    r^2*(3*Derivative[0, 1][H][r, t]^2 + 
      2*Derivative[0, 2][H][r, t]) + (c + 
      c*r*Derivative[1, 0][H][r, t])^2))/
 (E^(2*H[r, t])*(c^2*r^2))
eqthetatheta = (1/c^2)*E^(-2*F[r, t] + 2*H[r, t])* r*((-E^(2*F[r, t]))*
 r*(Derivative[0, 1][F][r, t]^2 + 
   Derivative[0, 1][F][r, t]*Derivative[0, 1][H][r, t] + 
   Derivative[0, 1][H][r, t]^2 + 
         Derivative[0, 2][F][r, t] + Derivative[0, 2][H][r, t]) + 
c^2*((-Derivative[1, 0][F][r, t])*(1 + 
      r*Derivative[1, 0][H][r, t]) + 

   Derivative[1, 0][H][r, t]*(2 + r*Derivative[1, 0][H][r, t]) + 
   r*Derivative[2, 0][H][r, t]))

precis = 30; Tsim = 10*T; Rsim = 10*R; 
NDSolve[{eqrr == 8*Pi*G*pressure, eqthetatheta == 0, F[r, -Tsim] == 0, H[r, -Tsim] == 0, 
    Derivative[1, 0][F][0, t] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][H][0, t] == 0, F[Rsim, t] == 0, 
    H[Rsim, t] == 0}, {F, H}, {t, -Tsim, Tsim}, {r, 0, Rsim}, WorkingPrecision -> precis, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> 
    {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 151,"MinPoints" -> 151, 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}, "TemporalVariable" -> t}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Ok thank you for your useful tips!

Comment: Add boundary conditions at `t = -Tsim` for the first derivatives of F and H with respect to time.

Comment: Additionally, because the equations contain derivatives in `r` no higher than first order, the boundary conditions can contain no derivatives in `r`.  Finally, the lower bound on `r` must be greater than zero to avoid the singularity there.

Answer (score 2):

As I noted in comments above, `NDSolve` has boundary value problems.  It needs boundary conditions at `t = -Tsim` for the first derivatives of `F` and `H` with respect to time, and it cannot have spatial boundary conditions involving derivatives of `F` with respect to `r`.  In the absence of additional information, I modified the arguments of `NDSolve` as follows.

```
sol = NDSolve[{eqrr == 8*Pi*G*pressure, eqthetatheta == 0, 
    F[r, -Tsim] == 0, H[r, -Tsim] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][H][r0, t] == 0,
    F[Rsim, t] == 0, H[Rsim, t] == 0, 
    (D[F[r, t], t] /. t -> -Tsim) == 0, (D[H[r, t], t] /. t -> -Tsim) == 0}, 
    {F, H}, {t, -Tsim, Tsim}, {r, r0, Rsim}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 151, 
    "MinPoints" -> 151, "TemporalVariable" -> t}]
```

with `r0 = 1/100` to avoid singularities at `r = 0`, and `Tsim = T` to reduce run time to a manageable amount.  The output is

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[{F[r, t], H[r, t]} /. sol], {t, -Tsim, -.22}, {r, r0, Rsim}, 
    PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Clearly, the computation is failing near `r = r0`.  To make progress, consider carefully the proper boundary conditions, as opposed to those I simply made up.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers. In fact, if T is sufficiently big, we should get the Scharwild metric with singularity for the metric at  R=GM/c^2. F, and H have first time derivative equal 0 at initial time of course . I completly forgot to write it in the code. I copy your answer in my code but it still does not work. Why you have not add: Derivative[1, 0][F][r0, t] == 0 also?

Comment: It will be simpler to send the all notebook to my gmail adress: zaganidis.alexis gmail com ??